# How can I remove the event listener from a class method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying remove a event listener from a function using the same reference that I add the event listener but the removeEventListener doesn't work

I want to the onScroll method stop listener the scroll.

```
export class LazyLoad {
    constructor(elementoScroll, porcentagem, objetoAxios) {
        this.elementoScroll = elementoScroll
        console.log(this.elementoScroll.scrollTop)
        this.porcentagem = porcentagem
        this.objetoAxios = objetoAxios
        this.endereco = objetoAxios
        this.addListener()
    }

    addListener() {
        this.elementoScroll.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), true);
    }

    onScroll(event) {
        console.log(event)
        let scrollPorcentagem = Math.floor(this.elementoScroll.scrollTop / (this.elementoScroll.scrollHeight - this.elementoScroll.clientHeight) * 100);
        if(scrollPorcentagem >= 90) {
            this.elementoScroll.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You might need to use `binding` like you did in the `addListener` function. `this.elementoScroll.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), true);`

Comment: Is it even entering the if block?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, that's incorrect, binding twice will result in two different functions. `obj.method.bind(obj) !== obj.method.bind(obj)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function parameter to your `addEventListener` and `reoveEventListener` calls are different. To see this, look at this simplified example:

```js
class X { method() {} }
let x = new X();
console.log(x.method.bind(x) === x.method); // false
```

To solve this, keep a reference to the function used when adding the event listener:

```
class LazyLoad {
  constructor(elementoScroll, porcentagem, objetoAxios) {
    this.elementoScroll = elementoScroll;
    console.log(this.elementoScroll.scrollTop);
    this.porcentagem = porcentagem;
    this.objetoAxios = objetoAxios;
    this.endereco = objetoAxios;
    this.addListener();
  }

  addListener() {
    this.listener = this.onScroll.bind(this);
    this.elementoScroll.addEventListener('scroll', listener, true);
  }

  onScroll(event) {
    console.log(event);
    let scrollPorcentagem = Math.floor(this.elementoScroll.scrollTop / (this.elementoScroll.scrollHeight - this.elementoScroll.clientHeight) * 100);
    if (scrollPorcentagem >= 90) {
      this.elementoScroll.removeEventListener('scroll', this.listener, true);
    }

  }
}
```